# What is the simplest way for me to use Google's APIs?

Tags: ruby, rest, google-api

Currently, I'm trying to get a list of advertisers (See http://code.google.com/apis/gan/v1beta1/advertisers/list.html) with my relationship status from Google's API.

I'm using Ruby and the 'google-api-client' gem and I'm writing this as an automated task.  I've suddenly been thrust in to their world of browser windows, shell scripts, and every nut and bolt of OAuth2.  I think I'm using the solution for a much different problem - accessing the data of people coming to your website.  I just want MY data.  Surely there's a much simpler way for me to get it?

Many other affiliate networks give me a REST service (or butchering thereof) and secret params/headers for auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've registered myself as user of my 'device'.  My app can now access my data!

I followed the instructions here:
https://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices.html

Is this the correct/best way to do it?  I am unsure.